# Error : Package restore failed when creating a new controller using view with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a new controller using View with Entity Framework

[image]

But I'm getting always the same error .

[image]

[image]

However, I'm trying many solutions but any of them worked for me:

- Clear caches and restore package .
- Delete ".vs" folder from your solution directory. After reopening solution, execute a "Clean Solution".
- Clear and Rebuild project.

How can I fix this error???

( Sorry the VS is in french )

Comment: Can you please convert the error message to English?

Comment: Have same problem, last time I solved by upgrading all entity framework nugets in project to highest version and updating dotnet entity framework tools to same version, worked for a while and now it does not again (they added new version), so it seems like it works ONLY with the highest EF version.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using VS UI for scaffolding, since it is really buggy (using .NET 6) and started using the command line scaffolder tool - **dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator**, there is no restore there and so far it works nicely without problems. I am using my own custom templates derived from original ones and works with those ones too.

for installing the tool use:

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

for creating full controller with CRUD views then you can do using:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator -p "yourpath\YourProject.csproj" controller -name YourController -m YourProject.Entity.YourEntity -dc YourDbContext -outDir Controllers -namespace YourProject.Controllers
```

More info you can find on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0